# Bootstrap column for image wont inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so i have a project where i have to make inline image like this

[image: something like this]

this is my code

```
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2>Exchange</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2>Community</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-lg">
                    <div class="col-lg" id="exchange">
                        <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
                        <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
                        <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Exchange -->
                    <div class="col-lg" id="community">
                        <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
                        <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
                        <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
                    </div>
```

but it turn out looking like this. im pretty sure when i use col 6 they will be inline with each other

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both snipped should be in the same column like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Exchange</h2>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg">
       <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
       <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
       <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Community</h2>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg">
       <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
       <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
       <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <h2>Exchange</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg" id="exchange">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  <h2>Community</h2>                 
  <div class="row-lg">
  <!-- Exchange -->
    <div class="col-lg" id="community">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
      <img src="dummy.jpg" alt="dummy">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```